# In the model layer, is it a good idea to compose types with IDs, as opposed to direct references?

Tags: c#, oop, model, composition

Although this question is in the context of MVVM, I think that it can be generalized to any MV* architecture.

When creating my model layer, I'm used to directly referencing objects to represent relationships, as such:

```
class Course {
 CourseID ID { get; }
 string Name { get; }
}
class Student {
 IEnumerable<Course> EnrolledCourses { get; }
}
```

However, I've found that the reconstruction of such object hierarchies from storage is becoming increasingly onerous. Without the benefits of DI at the model layer, I'm left facing the unhappy choice of using a heavy ORM with all the attendant attributes and other headaches, or of using a micro-ORM (my preference) and then painstakingly reconstructing the object graphs by hand.

I'm playing around with the idea of ditching direct references entirely, in favor of something like:

```
class Course {
 CourseID ID { get; }
 string Name { get; }
}
class Student {
 IEnumerable<CourseID> EnrolledCourses { get; }
}
```

This way, my model layer starts to more closely resemble relational data, which I've always assumed was traditionally frowned upon (thus the preference for ORMs).

In my code, the app's data is usually exposed to higher levels by the Repository pattern, as reactive feeds and/or iEnumerables. This makes it trivially easy to retrieve and display related data on demand via queries and/or filters by keys. Not quite as easy as a direct reference, but close.

So - what's the main argument AGAINST modeling domain objects without references to other types? Also, I've tried to find discussion about this but haven't seen much, could it be that I'm missing the right search terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any application you want maintainable you need to respect separation of concerns. MV* is always part of the UI layer and most of the time you also have a Business (domain) layer and a Persistence Layer (DAL).

SoC means you get to focus on one layer at the time. The ViewModel is designed for the View, Domain model cares only about business and Persistence Model knows about saving and querying. These are related but *are not the same* and it's best to think of them as different.

When you're modeling the Domain you don't care about the other layers, you want to best represent the business concepts (and this is very tricky as a lot of them seems easy to model, but it's a trap!) and use cases of those concepts. There aren't any references here, there are only business processes using business concepts i.e you should think at a higher level not at a technical level even if you're writing code.

For example, the code you showed us really looks like a view model, because the Domain concept of Student probably doesn't involve Courses (Your view needs them together).  You have Student, Course and these two concepts are **working together** for a number of business scenarios. It might be better (I don't know exact details for your Domain) to have a service whose purpose is to enroll Students in Course.

From the persistence point of view, you might have something as a repository of enrolled students i.e a collection of CourseId and StudentId. Probably the service I've mentioned above can be implemented directly in the persistence if it doesn't contain business logic. Pretty much all design decisions require the proper understanding of the Domain so I'm just guessing here, but I'm trying to show how to think.

Be aware that for different contexts you really don't need the full object, only its 'short' form which usually means a reference (as in an Id). But from the context point of view, that reference represents a concept. Note that the entities or references are not there for navigational purposes. They are there because they help define a domain concept.

Also, it makes little sense to define a business object with the single purpose to act as a container for others. In domain modelling, the **has** relationship should be viewed as *is defined by*.

You should get familiar with CQRS (separating writes from reads). This will make saving/restoring the business model trivial while allowing you to get wild with queries. And you won't be needing an ORM .

Bottom line, you should model things according to the layer(concern) you're working in. Then use mappers to to 'translate' the relevant model from one layer/context to another. Don't try to create the ultimate model which will fit all the purposes.